# Can I get my signature design created in Signatures through api?

Tags: docusignapi

After I log in with my sandbox account, I can add signatures for my account.
Can I get my signature design created in Signatures through api?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL7Nb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You make the REST API Call for this route:

```
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureId}/{imageType}
```

(&transparent_png=true if you need that)

You can update the signature or initials.
The body of your HTTP request should include a 64 bit encoded of the binary image file.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/UserSignatures/updateImage